# Rails scopes, filtering all by date and child data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I have a model called "Campaign" and it `belongs_to` a "Schedule".

A Campaign has a start and end date, and the Schedule contains information such as "Every Monday", "Every day", etc.

I'm wanting to select all the Campaigns that are valid for a specific date.

```
# campaign.rb
scope :active,      -> { where(status: true) }
scope :inactive,    -> { where(status: false) }

def valid_for(date)
  includes(:schedules).where("
        ( start_at >= ? AND (end_at IS NULL OR end_at <= ? ) )
        AND schedules.days_of_week = ?",
        date,
        date,
        date.wday
    )
end
```

And in my Campaign spec (the Campaign and Schedule does exist in the test):

```
expect(Campaign.active.valid_for("2015-06-15".to_date).size).to eq 1
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
undefined method `valid_for' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

I cannot use a class method for `self.valid_for` because I need to be able to access the attributes `start_at` and `end_at`, as well as the parent schedule. However, it doesn't seem to be working as an instance method either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a scope and use a scope argument:

```
scope :valid_for, ->(date) {
  includes(:schedules).where("
        ( start_at >= ? AND (end_at IS NULL OR end_at <= ? ) )
        AND schedules.days_of_week = ?,
        start_at,
        end_at,
        date.wday
    ")
}
```

This will limit your access to the `start_at` and `end_at` though. You'll need to get those from the database or pass them in as args to your scope.

Comment: This doesn't allow me to include the `active` scope like I want to in the test. This is basically a class method, which is what I mentioned as not being what I wanted to use (and reasons given) in the question. Edit: However, you did help me see that I'm querying the DB with `start_at` and `end_at` when I should be using `date` in both of those places! Thanks :)

Comment: This shouldn't prevent you from using the `active` scope. Scopes can be combined, which is really the crux of the issue you're facing as calling a scope returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not an instance of your model.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Finbarr. You got me heading in the right direction when you mentioned the start/end dates. This eventually led to me successfully finding the solution. I'm also using the `scope :valid_for` suggestion, and it's working great. Thanks again